# Node XHR file upload events

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Consider an ExpressJS app which receives file uploads:

```
app.post('/api/file', function(req, res) {
    req.on('data', function() {
        console.log('asd')
    })
})
```

I can't understand why data event is never fired. 
I'm also using bodyParser() middleware which gives me the following object for each file which seems to have some events available but still no effect:

```
{
    file: {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: 10,
        size: 43330194,
        path: 'public/uploads/a4abdeae32d56a2494db48e9b0b22a5e.deb',
        name: 'google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb',
        type: 'application/x-deb',
        hash: null,
        lastModifiedDate: Sat Aug 24 2013 20: 59: 00 GMT + 0200(CEST),
        _writeStream: {
            _writableState: [Object],
            writable: true,
            domain: null,
            _events: {},
            _maxListeners: 10,
            path: 'public/uploads/a4abdeae32d56a2494db48e9b0b22a5e.deb',
            fd: null,
            flags: 'w',
            mode: 438,
            start: undefined,
            pos: undefined,
            bytesWritten: 43330194,
            closed: true,
            open: [Function],
            _write: [Function],
            destroy: [Function],
            close: [Function],
            destroySoon: [Function],
            pipe: [Function],
            write: [Function],
            end: [Function],
            setMaxListeners: [Function],
            emit: [Function],
            addListener: [Function],
            on: [Function],
            once: [Function],
            removeListener: [Function],
            removeAllListeners: [Function],
            listeners: [Function]
        },
        open: [Function],
        toJSON: [Function],
        write: [Function],
        end: [Function],
        setMaxListeners: [Function],
        emit: [Function],
        addListener: [Function],
        on: [Function],
        once: [Function],
        removeListener: [Function],
        removeAllListeners: [Function],
        listeners: [Function]
    }
}
```

I would like to understand how to make progress and complete events work.

Comment: Do you have documentation that pointed you to write this code?  I've [seen it done differently](http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads).

Comment: I'm uploading the files with an xmlhttprequest instead of regular html form. However data event is available on req object so it should fire once any request comes in (?)

Comment: The body is already parsed at the body parser middleware. Remove it and you'll get the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the request and response objects are accessible in Express, the request has already ended, and the upload is already complete. Therefore, the `data` event won't fire anymore, because there is no more data to receive (and the readable stream has been consumed as per Jonathan Ong's comment). An alternative way to find the file upload progress would be with middleware, specifically the body parser.

When looking at the Connect documentation [here](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html) (since Express is built on Connect), it states this:

> `defer` defers processing and exposes the Formidable form object as
>   `req.form.next()` is called without waiting for the form's "end" event.
>   This option is useful if you need to bind to the "progress" event.

So all you have to do is add set `defer` to true when initializing the body parser, then you can listen on the `progress` event for `req.form`. Example here:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({
  defer: true              
}));

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  req.form.on('progress', function (received, total) {
    var percent = (received / total * 100) | 0;
    console.log(percent + '% has been uploaded.');
  });

  req.form.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Upload completed.');
  });
});
```

Comment: req and res are still streams/eventemitters. the readable stream has just already been consumed.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any data event bind with express req object. Where have you seen that?

And also, try adding this on the form you use to upload:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: the req object is a stream. of course it has data events. the body parser just consumes it.